# Android, PHP and SQL, why and intermediary between the two?

Tags: php, android, database

I'm new to Android programming and I'm trying to create an app which needs a persistent remote database. Now, coming from Java and local databases, I've always connected application and database directly, without an intermediary. 
I'm not seeing the point of this workaround, can someone please make this clear? I've tried searching on Google, but it seems everybody assumes this as a principles (or maybe I need to look for better keywords).

Comment: You need a backend server which responds to android's requests. And usally they talk with each other using `http` protocol. Keywords to look `REST API`, `API`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most important argument that I can think of right now is **SECURITY/QUERY VERIFICATION**.
You most likely want to use an online database (perhaps MySQL) because you want to store shared information between ALL users of your application in it. The major difference between a local and an online database is that many many users have access to it - both writing and reading access.

So imagine you have your android application and now want to save some user generated data from it in your online database. Assume there is no PHP intermediary: The app directly sends the finished MySQL request to the database.
But what happens if someone looks into the source code of your app or uses any other way to manipulate that request? Let's say he changes a query from

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE ID=9434896
```

to

```
SELECT * FROM user
```

Exactly - he gets all information from your `user` data table, including sensitive data such as passwords or E-Mail Addresses.
What evaluates these queries and prevents them from happening?
Your app surely doesn't, because the user can easily manipulate/change the app.
Your MySQL database doesn't check them either, because it always assumes that the query is what the developer actually wanted. As long as the syntax is correct, it will execute it.

And that's what you need the PHP intermediary for:
You send values to a PHP file (e.g. `check_login.php` receives the values `267432`(userid) and `hie8774h7dch37` (password)), the PHP file then checks if these values are actually a userid (e.g. "Are they numeric values only?") and then builds a MySQL query out of it.
This way the user has no way to manipulate the query as he wishes. (He can still send wrong values; but depending on the situation it is also possible for a PHP script to check if the values are legit or not)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this will give you some context. I built a game on Android and iPhone, and I wanted high scores stored in a remote database.

Security is the main reason you would do this. You should always do data validation on the server side, not client side. By doing it this way, my php script can validate input before making changes on the database. In addition, it is not safe to store database credentials in your apk file. This opens up a range of security vulnerabilities. Safer to keep this on the server side.

Secondly, by utilizing a single PHP script, I only need to debug/manage code that validates data and interacts with my database in 1 place... the php file. This saves me plenty of time rather than updating all of the queries and validating criteria in both the iPhone and Android instances.

I am sure there are other benefits to this approach, but these are the reasons why I do it this way.

Answer (score 1):

It's an abstraction layer. You don't want to code your app to MySQL and then discover your backend is moving to MS-SQL.  Also, you control how you present information to the user.  If they have access, they can read everything.  If you have an abstraction layer, then they can only get information by going through the proper channels.